# Preamble not found in subfile when using \input{Preamble.tex} in main file

Tags: input, preamble, subfiles

When using the following for my main TeX file `Graduation_report.tex`, in the main folder:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\input{Preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

\subfile{Introduction/Introduction.tex}

\end{document}
```

and the following for my subfile `Introduction.tex` (which is in the folder `Introduction`)

```
\documentclass[../Graduation_report.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

I get the error '`Preamble.tex not found`'. However, when I just paste my Preamble in the main file (`Graduation_report.tex`), instead of using `\input`, it works. Is there a solution to input my preamble in the main file? So that I can create my preamble in a separate TeX file and still run my subfiles separately with the same preamble.

Comment: Where exactly is `Preamble.tex` in relation to `Graduation_report.tex`?

Comment: Using `subfiles` with sub-directories isn't a good idea. You could extend environment variable `TEXINPUTS` or modify `\input@path` similar to package `import`.

Comment: daleif, my Preamble.tex is in the same folder as Graduation_report.tex

Comment: Yes, but `./Introduction/Introduction.tex` is not. Subfiles package causes `./Introduction/Introduction.tex` to be compiled with `./Graduation_report.tex` preamble, therefore the complier searches `\input{Preamble.tex}` (you can omit `.tex`) inside the folder `./Introduction/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by defining the input path for the preamble in my main file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

% Define path Preamble
\makeatletter 
\def\input@path{{../}} 
\makeatother
\input{Preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\subfile{Introduction/Introduction.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't do that and it worked. It may be because I have \usepackage{subfiles} outside of Preamble.tex